# Instantiate once

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, instance

I know that it is a commonly asked question but, I swear I did what I had to do so I am turning to you guys to tell me what is wrong with my work that.

I have to spawn an "indicator above an object after it gets thrown by another object, so I am having a code to tell the system to instantiate this object above the other one as an indication, after the velocity.magnitude of the main one gets to 0 and to guarantee that is is only instantiated once I put a bool to ensure my condition, now the instantiated object gets instantiated once as soon as my projects loads and in a really wrong position (because of the first state of my object which is still ) and even getting my position and ensuring that the instantiation process start only if my last position - my actual one is not equal to 0, the problem persist. I know it is not clear enough so ask me and I will answer and this is my code:

```
public bool isCreated = false;
    public Vector3 lastPosition;
    void Update()
    {

        if (!isCreated)
        {
                if ((gameObject.GetComponent<Item>().name =="blue" ||
                 gameObject.GetComponent<Item>().name =="green")&&
                GameObject.Find("blue").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude == 0 &&
                (gameObject.transform.position - lastPosition != null))
            {
                Instantiate (indice, new Vector3 (gameObject.transform.localPosition.x ,
                                                  gameObject.transform.localPosition.y + 2,
                                                  gameObject.transform.localPosition.z),
                                 Quaternion.identity);
                isCreated=true;
            }

            //  step3 = true;   
        } 
     ![enter image description here][1]}
        void start()


        {
            lastPosition = gameObject.transform.position;  
        }
```

Comment: So the problem is that you only want `Instantiate` to be called once but it is incorrectly getting called as soon as the application starts due to the initial state of the objects?

Comment: Can't you just make sure the relevant objects are initiated to values which can't satisfy the condition until the appropriate time, i.e, initialise `velocity.magnitude` to `int.MaxValue` as opposed to 0?

Comment: i tried to make it equal to something different than 0 and it says that magnitude is read only parameter :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the condition:

```
(gameObject.transform.position - lastPosition != null)
```

To:

```
(gameObject.transform.position - lastPosition != default(Vector3))
```

Or possibly:

```
(lastPosition != null)
```

I'm not sure what exactly your trying to check against from code you have posted.

Comment: with (gameObject.transform.position - lastPosition != default(Vector3)) 
they just never got instantiated , and with  (lastPosition != null) they got instanciated wrongly like (gameObject.transform.position - lastPosition != null)

:(

i am trying to check :

Comment: How could `gameObject.transform.position - lastPosition)` ever equal null? That condition is always going to be true isn't it?

Comment: in the start function i took a value lastposition to compaire it with the actual position each fame but yea i think =!default(vector3) is the right way to test it... but still nothing 

am trying to test : that the object is the blue or the green object AND that its velocity is equal to 0 so it is not in move and that this 0 value is not from the firsts frames where my objects are all velocities.magnitudes == 0. sorry for my poor logic i am a beginner and i have to show something turning soon for my EOS project so ... thats why this quick guesses.

Comment: Hey i just changed this condition to  if( Time.time >1 ) and it worked ^^ thanks it was obvious idk why i didn't try this from the beinnings :p, they have spawned in a wrong Z position though but i will fix this thanks again.